# angelleye/paypal-php-library recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal

[here is the angelleye paypal library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library)

```
$PayPal = new angelleye\PayPal\PayPal($PayPalConfig);

$GRPPDFields = array(
                   'profileid' => 'I-3WEY3EAYCV0R'          // Profile ID of the profile you want to get details for.
                   );

$PayPalRequestData = array('GRPPDFields'=>$GRPPDFields);


$PayPalResult =
$PayPal->GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails($PayPalRequestData);


?>
```

This is the recurring payment sample api. But i am new to it and don't know how to integrate on php4 on button click. Please help me to solve this out

Comment: The class library uses namespacing and will not work with PHP 4.  You will need to update to at least PHP 5.3, but really at this point 7.0+ is recommended.

Comment: ok..i have updated to php 7.0. but i am getting error from sample DPRP error. i have bussinees pro acct.

Comment: Need to know the error you're getting then..??

Comment: Undefined index: XMLResponse ....using : $PayPal = new angelleye\PayPal\PayPal($PayPalConfig);

Comment: Are you sure your site is running on PHP 7.0 now?  Sometimes people update their server but not the individual site they're working on.